# Capabilities we can have inside remote event receivers

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, remote-event-receiver

I have an on-premises SharePoint 2013 site, and the site has a  custom list, and this list has an event receiver linked to it, where the event receiver do the following steps, when a list item is approved:

1. Create a new sub-site using a custom site template. the sub-site's url will be equal to the list item ID. also the sub-site's description will be equal to the list item description field.
2. Define that the new sub-site will have unique permissions.
3. Create 2 SharePoint groups, add users to them and associate them with the new sub-site.
4. modify the left side navigation to have links to the new security groups.
5. also when the list item description is updates, the related sub-site's description will be updated.

Now i want to migrate my site collection to SharePoint online, and i am going to convert the above event receiver to be a remove event receiver, which will do the exact steps as above, but instead of creating a sub-site the remove event receiver will do these steps:-

1. create a new modern team site collection.
2. link the new modern team site collection with a modern hub site.
3. since we can not create a new modern team site collection from a site template (as we do in the sub-site case).. then i will have to create some custom lists and custom documents libraries. for example i will need to create a custom content type >> add a managed metadata site column to it (which will be linked to a term set) >> create a new docuemnt library inside the new site collection which will use the custom content type.
4. do all the other operation as define inside the above server-side event receiver.
5. also i need to modify the defualt permission level for the modern team site member group from Edit to Contribute.

so generally speaking should i be able to develop a remove event recevier which can do all the above steps?

Comment: Yes, you can do this.

Comment: Yes you can do this, pretty much everything you have mentioned with remote Event receiver of SharePoint Online

Comment: @DerekGusoff so even the new functionalities, such as associating a sharepoint modern team site with a hub site are available inside remote event receivers (inside CSOM)??

Answer (score 0):

If you not have limits about time difference in time list item updated (created) and site created (updated) then you can make your life easier. 
You can use some periodically running code with more easy to use code architecture. 
Create Console App and schedule it in Windows Task Scheduler.
It is easier way, by my opinion then to understand how to create complex remote event receiver. May be I am wrong but it is my opinion.
Or use some other periodically running code.
One thing I cannot approve -

> modify the left side navigation to have links to the new security
>   groups.

May be here you cannot do this by server code.